# date time format in SAS that can't be exported in Excel 2007

Tags: datetime, sas

Good Morning,

A program in SAS is about to select/merge/sort dates/times in alphanumeric value (ex : 14-Jan-2013 07:00:00.479) inside a lot of tables and to create a single table.
This program use the instruction "format E8601" and several lines after "format type $10.;
informat type $10.;", what transforms the dates in a numeric value (ex : 2013-01-14T07:02:03.647).
When this table is exported in Excel 2007, the value becomes "   " and can't be modified in a traditional date/time format.

How to do it ? Is there any other format (instead of E8601) which can be used to keep the date in text or in a alphanumeric value ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: by alphanumeric you mean as string? have you read this http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm? you can create a string like put(dt,datetime.)

Comment: How are you exporting it (what is your code and/or what wizard are you using)?

Answer (score 1):

SAS datetime values are internally represented as floating point values equal to the number of seconds since January 1, 1960.  `FORMATS` are used to control how those numeric values are externally represented. For example, consider this:

```
data have;
  myDateTime1 = '14-Jan-2013 07:00:00.479'dt;
  myDateTime2 = '14-Jan-2013 07:00:00.479'dt;
  myDateTime3 = '14-Jan-2013 07:00:00.479'dt;

  format myDateTime2 datetime23.3
         myDateTime3 E8601DT23.3;

  put myDateTime1= 'as a number'
    / myDateTime2= 'as a normal SAS datetime'
    / myDateTime3= 'as an ISO 8601 datetime'
   ;
run;
```

When run, this is shown in the SAS log:

```
myDateTime1=1673766000.5 as a number
myDateTime2=14JAN2013:07:00:00.479 as a normal SAS datetime
myDateTime3=2013-01-14T07:00:00.479 as an ISO 8601 datetime
```

Note the three `myDateTime` variables have the same value but are displayed differently based on the `format` specified.

Assuming you have SAS Access to PC File Formats licensed, you can just use `PROC EXPORT` to create an Excel workbook:

```
proc export data=have
     outfile='c:\temp\test_dates.xlsx'
     replace;
run;
```

The data values in the Excel workbook for the two variables formatted as "datetime" values will appear correctly as Excel columns.  However, the default formatting in Excel only shows the "date" portion; to display the complete value in Excel you will need to change the Excel column formats.